# Are there any differences between partitioning and layering terminology?

Tags: architecture

MSDN have some word docs on how to correctly partition and layer an application. However, what, if any,  differences exist between partitioning and layering?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post links to thee doc's please?

Comment: Hi, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rampup/default.aspx sorry I don't have Silverlight on this machine so can't navigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you are working on a web site about cooking where people can read recipes and discuss food they have made. You could partition the site into a content management system to look after the recipes, and a forum for discussions. Both parts of the website could still be made up of layers, for example a database layer and a presentation layer.